# How can I get access to Boomerang?

Tags: pathfinder-2e, pathfinder-society

[Boomerang](https://2e.aonprd.com/Weapons.aspx?ID=332) is an uncommon weapon. As it has no racial trait, it not suitable for Unconventional Weaponry.

How can I get access to it in PFS?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### An Achievement Point Boon

The only way to access a Boomerang currently is the Avid Collector - Treasure Vault Armor & Armaments boon for 20 achievement points. You can see the full text of the boon at the [Organized Play FAQ](https://paizo.com/pathfindersociety/faq). The boon can be purchased on your [My Organized Play](https://paizo.com/organizedplay/myAccount) page on the Boons tab under Rewards purchaseable with Achievement Points.